# SQL Multi table select query

Tags: mysql, select

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbUTI.jpg

I want to Do a multi select in one query where one table has data from many tables.
i have four tables to combine it into a single output.
here is a image of my table.

i want to select all and don't want other data from other table just main table with name of all other tables

have tried following but its not working.

```
    select * from project_content 
    left Join project_master on project_master.id =  project_content.p_id
    left Join project_content_menu on project_content_menu.type_id =  project_content.p_c_id 
    left Join project_menu_master on project_menu_master.id =  project_content.m_id 


    select * from project_content 
    left Join project_master on project_master.id =  project_content.p_id
    left Join project_content_menu on project_content_menu.type_id =  project_content.p_c_id 
    left Join project_menu_master on project_menu_master.id =  project_content.m_id 


    select distinct(*) from project_content 
    left OUTER Join   project_master on project_master.id =  project_content.p_id
    left OUTER Join   project_content_menu on project_content_menu.type_id =  project_content.p_c_id 
    left OUTER Join  project_menu_master on project_menu_master.id =  project_content.m_id 

    select * from project_content ,project_master,project_content_menu,project_menu_master
    where project_master.id =  project_content.p_id and project_content_menu.type_id =  project_content.p_c_id and project_menu_master.id =  project_content.m_id 

    select pc.id as id , pm.name as pname , pmm.name as menuname , pcm.name as contentname , pc.name as name
    from 
    project_content as pc,
    project_master as pm,
    project_content_menu as pcm,
    project_menu_master as pmm
    where 
    pm.id = pc.p_id 
    and 
    pcm.type_id = pc.m_id
    and 
    pmm.id = pc.p_c_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undesrtood you correctly, you want the data just from the main table, but with names instead of foreign keys from other tables? If so, then:

```
SELECT pc.id, pm.name, pcm.name, pmm.name, pc.name, pc.desc, pc.thumb, pc.src, pc.status
FROM project_content AS pc
LEFT JOIN project_master AS pm ON pm.id =  pc.p_id
LEFT JOIN project_content_menu AS pcm ON pcm.type_id = pc.p_c_id 
LEFT JOIN project_menu_master AS pmm ON pmm.id = pc.m_id
```

Comment: yes u got me Right.
But i am Getting Duplicate Rows in Main Table .

See  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaf9L.jpg

Comment: @user1418790: thats because you have duplicates in project_content_menu type_id column - shouldn't foreign key be it's id column instead?

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert in SQL but you could try using `UNION` operator. like this:

```
select names
from table1
where lastname like k%
UNION
select names
from table2
where lastname like k%
```

This will combine the result from table1 and table2 and display UNIQUE NAMES in the result where the lastname is starting with k. so, if there is a JOHN KRAMER and JOHN KUTCHER then only JOHN will be displayed once.
If you want duplicate entries , too, then use `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, that I understood your problem well, but if you need to add all records together, you should use: **[UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)**

Like:

```
select name from project_content

UNION ALL

select name from project_master 

UNION ALL

select name from project_master 

UNION ALL

select name from project_menu_master
```

Just be sure, that you have the same amount of columns in each select with the same type